# AWS IoT | How to add Lambda trigger when WebSocket connection is established and ended?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm building a chat application using Angular as frontend and AWS Lambda, Dynamodb and IoT Core as backend.

The connection between clients is using MQTT WebSocket (publish/subscribe) via IoT Core.

Now, I want to generate a list of online users.

**Question:** Is it possible to add a trigger to IoT when a WebSocket connection is established (a user is online) and another trigger when a WebSocket connection is ended (user offline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two [reserved topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html) that can be used to monitor connections and disconnections.

These are `$aws/events/presence/connected/clientId` and `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/clientId`.

An AWS IoT rule can subscribe to `$aws/events/presence/#` or `$aws/events/presence/connected/+`/`$aws/events/presence/disconnected/+` and trigger a Lambda to process the connection/disconnection.